# Dialing bar in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, pjsip

i'm developing android app using "pjsip" library, i made it to integrate it inside my app and tested and made calls ,i want to create something like dialing bar when the call is in the background , where i can click it and show the call screen for example.
this is one of the function i used.

```
public void acceptCall(View view) {
        incomingCall = true;
        CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam();
        prm.setStatusCode(pjsip_status_code.PJSIP_SC_OK);
        try {
            currentCall.answer(prm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.3f);
        alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        answer.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);

    }
```

Comment: What is a "dialing bar"?

Comment: when you are trying to make a call and it's ringing when u exit from the call screen u will see a bar in the top in green with text "dialing"

Comment: you mean something like samsung devices does, a icon which appears on top, when you press home on dialing screen?

Comment: yes exactly  that is what i want